# Azure Mobile Services .NET backend with SharePoint domain manager

Tags: sharepoint, azure-mobile-services

We have data stored in Office 365 SharePoint that we would like listed in a custom iOS business app. The offline sync of Azure Mobile Services is awesome and I have seen with the .NET backend, a custom domain manager can be created.

I haven't found any implementation of this particular case online. Would this type of offline sync with azure mobile services to iOS and SharePoint work? And if so, is there an example of a custom domain manager with DTO objects that works with SharePoint 2013 in Office 365?

Comment: did you get any further information from Microsoft, or get a solution to this? I'm after the same information.

Comment: Nothing yet. I did see they release a CRM Domain Manager. May be similar design which could form the basis of a SharePoint one, but I haven't looked into it again

Comment: James, got reply pointing to this repo an unfinished start https://github.com/lindydonna/mobile-demos/tree/proxydomain/OData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a sample yet that will do this, but in the works we have a sample OData domain manager. Assuming that the OData Sharepoint feed exposes everything you need, this could be a good solution. And, offline sync and all other Mobile Services functionality will just work.

Otherwise, you'd have to write your own domain manager, which is not particularly easy. We will eventually expand our built-in domain managers to include more popular data sources, and Sharepoint would very likely be included there. However, we don't yet have an ETA for this, as the work hasn't even been planned yet.

If you email mobileservices@microsoft.com, I can let you know when the OData Domain Manager sample is ready.

In the meantime, you should also try out this tutorial (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-calling-sharepoint-on-behalf-of-user/) for connecting to Sharepoint resources from your mobile services controllers.